# jquery validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I've this jquery code, loading a remote page with a parameter from an input text form

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        $('#result').load("/api.php", {
            'url': $("input:text[name=url]").val()
        });
    });
});
```

I need to validate the input text, that is a url.

How can I use the Validate plugin to do validation before the submit?

Answer (score 1):

In your PHP page just return `true` or an error message, e.g. `"This site isn't allowed"` (note the difference, `true` isn't quoted).

Then use [the `remote` rule](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote#options), like this:

```
$("form").validate({
  rules: {
    url: {
      remote: "/api.php"
    }
  }
});
```

By default it'll send one query pair, the element's name (already `url`) and it's value, exactly what you were passing before.  A string is treated as the error message and `true` is treated as passing validation.

It's worth noting this rule is special, it'll wait on the AJAX request to finish before validation completes, so it's all in the same bucket, not a separate validation process/step.

Answer (score 0):

Using the jQuery Validate plugin you can specify the validation on the form as follows;

```
$('form').validate({
  rules: {
    firstname: "required",
    surname: "required"
  },
  success: function() {
    $('#result').load("/api.php", {
       'url': $("input:text[name=url]").val()
    });
  },
});
```

Hopefully this will get you started, further information on the various options available can be found at: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation